# BroadcastReceiver with SmsMessage

Tags: android

Application is being developed in 2.3.3. 
I am testing the application in Emulators..

Task ::: Whenever a new message arrives, I have to display the sender and the text of the message in a Toast.

Problem ::: Toast doesn't get displayed.

My Code File :::

```
package com.callee.helper;


import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class CalleeHelperActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent receivedIntent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Bundle b = receivedIntent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str ="";

        if(b!=null)
        {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[])b.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
            {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                str += "SMS from "+ msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += " : ";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";
            }

            Toast.makeText(arg0, str, 50).show();

        }
        else{
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "There is a problem", 50).show();
        }
    }
}
```

My AndroidManifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.callee.helper"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <receiver android:name=".CalleeHelperActivity">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>   

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I cannot trace where the problem is. Can someone please help me...

I tried to set a break point in onReceive(), but it doesn't hit. What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you make sure that your `onReceive` method being called when receiving a message? Have u tried set a break point?

Comment: I have set a break point. But it didn't hit the break point... What could be the reason?

Comment: 50 is not a proper value. read the documentation.

Comment: if you don't hit your breakpoint, put a breakpoint earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [RECEIVE_SMS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_SMS) permission to monitor incoming messages. So, add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

to your manifest, and you should be good to go ;)